# Bind a SerialPort to a Windows Docker container

Tags: docker

I'm currently playing around with Docker container and I have figured out binding port but I also need to bind a USB serial port to my docker container from my host machine. So the docker container listens onto the communication on the USB serial port.

Currently I have tried running:

```
docker run -t 'imagesName' --isolation=process --device="class/Interface Class GUID"
```

But when I inspect the docker container I get:

```
docker inspect 'DockerID'

"HostConfig":{ "Devices":[] }
```

I can see that the docker has run the commands as

```
"Cmd": [ 
"--isolation=process"
"--device=class/ Interface Class GUID" ]
```

Ofc i set my Interface Class GUID accordingly to microsofts documentation [Devices in Containers on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/hardware-devices-in-containers?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5002324)

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: We found a better solution or different setup that ended up replacing the docker needs. But yea I got it to work, can't 100% remember where it was wrong but it had to do with the parameter setup in the "docker run -t"